# Is there a way to create a pandas dataframe from extracting data from a string like data

Tags: python, pandas

My data is as follows

```
{'first_name': 'sandy', 'last_name': 'Joy', 'company': 'xyz', 'address_1': 'Upper hill Nairobi, hospital road, FORTIS SUITES', 'address_2': '-1.2808879508554905,36.82423747075825', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': 'KE', 'email': 'atienxxxandy@gmail.com', 'phone': '+25470xxx487'}

{'first_name': 'Alice', 'last_name': 'Kimani', 'company': '', 'address_1': 'Mayfair business center parklands', 'address_2': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': 'KE', 'email': 'githaxxxxce615@gmail.com', 'phone': '+254xxxx07329'}
```

Desired Output

```
first_name   last_name      company   address_1                                      ....other columns
1. sandy          Atieno     xyz     Upper hill Nairobi, hospital road, FORTIS SUITES 
2. Alice          Kimani             Mayfair business center parklands
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put all your dict to a list and then create a dataframe directly from that list:

```
data = [{'first_name': 'sandy', 'last_name': 'Joy', 'company': 'xyz', 'address_1': 'Upper hill Nairobi, hospital road, FORTIS SUITES', 'address_2': '-1.2808879508554905,36.82423747075825', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': 'KE', 'email': 'atienxxxandy@gmail.com', 'phone': '+25470xxx487'},
        {'first_name': 'Alice', 'last_name': 'Kimani', 'company': '', 'address_1': 'Mayfair business center parklands', 'address_2': '', 'city': '', 'state': '', 'postcode': '', 'country': 'KE', 'email': 'githaxxxxce615@gmail.com', 'phone': '+254xxxx07329'}]

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a built in JSON parser, `pandas.read_json()`, which you can read about here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

It is pretty powerful for handling various layouts of json structured data, but if your data has some quirks (it looks like you have json objects on different lines, rather than a json list of objects) it may be easier to parse the file first into a list of dicts, then convert that to a dataframe. Python has a built-in json module that you could feed each line into with `json.loads()`. Read about that here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html